# MVC communication, update label from model class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, model-view-controller, uilabel

I have a Model class, which has two methods:

```
func callElements() -> String {
    if(count < elementsToShow.count - 1) {
        count += 1
        var element = elementsToShow[count]
        println(element)
        return element
    } else {
        return "No more buttons"
    }
}

func changeLabel(){
    var callV = ViewController().label
    var elementCall = callElements()
    println("111")
    callV.text = elementCall // in this line I am having and error saying: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
}
```

And a Controller class which has a button and a label. From the Controller class I am trying to call methodes on the Model class and show the output on the label which is called `label`.

```
@IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton) {
    modelFrom.changeLabel()
    modelFrom.callElements()     
}
```

But I am having error in Model class in this line : `callV.text = elementCall`.

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I need these methods to be in Model class because the same label needs to change from other Controller classes (when other buttons are clicked in other classes). This is just a simple idea because I need to implement this idea in much more complex app.

Or maybe protocols/delegates are better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is here

```
var callV = ViewController().label
```

You are creating a new instance of `ViewController`,you should get the reference of the existing one

You can pass in a label as input

```
func changeLabel(label:UILabel){
var elementCall = callElements()
println("111")
label.text = elementCall 
}
```

Then call

```
modelFrom.callElements(self.label)
```

Update:
**I suggest you a better design**

1. This is your logic function in your `Model`(Well,I do not think this is model part here)

   ```
   func callElements() -> String {
       if(count < elementsToShow.count - 1) {
       count += 1
       var element = elementsToShow[count]
       println(element)
       return element
   } else {
       return "No more buttons"
   ```

   }
    }
2. In the `viewController` your label in:

Keep a property as the text Of Label,then when property update,update the label

```
 var labelText:String?{
    didSet{
        label.text = labelText
    }
}
```

Then

```
@IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton) {
   labelText = modelFrom.changeLabel()
}
```

3. Then in the second view controller, if your first view controller is not visiable when your second view controller is on screen. You just need to pass your new value back to `labelText`. This is about **passing value between ViewControllers**,is you use storyboard,you can use delegate or protocol to pass value back

Comment: Wonderful it worked perfectly. But can I call now the same method in another Controller class and update the same label. But without using segue. I tried to call exactly the same but it dose not work because I don not have `label` defined in that class (SecondController).

Comment: Thank you, the thing is that I can not use segue because I am using SWRevealviewController a library to make slide out menus. But can I pass values between viewControllers with delegates and protocols

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to pass value back.Just select the right one. If my answer solve your problem,please accept it

Comment: just one more clarification `label.text = text` should it be `label.text = labelText`